# Prestashop Import CSV Error - Duplicate entry for key PRIMARY

Tags: mysql, import, reference, duplicates, prestashop

I am trying to import a CSV containing products in **Prestashop 1.6.1.9** and I get the following error: **Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'**. The CSV doesn't contain a column with ID, but contains a column containing the products reference, which is unique for every product. On import, only the 1st row (1st product) gets inserted into the database.

I am using the **"Use product reference as key"** set to **Yes** when importing through the CSV Import. The reference codes look like this: **A.VOO3211515113QDISCOVERERSTT**, **A.VXX32115156113SMA761OWL** and so on.

Here is the SQL generated in the error:

```
INSERT INTO `psmo_product` (`id_shop_default`, `id_manufacturer`, `id_supplier`, `reference`, `supplier_reference`, `location`, `width`, `height`, `depth`, `weight`, `quantity_discount`, `ean13`, `upc`, `cache_is_pack`, `cache_has_attachments`, `is_virtual`, `id_category_default`, `id_tax_rules_group`, `on_sale`, `online_only`, `ecotax`, `minimal_quantity`, `price`, `wholesale_price`, `unity`, `unit_price_ratio`, `additional_shipping_cost`, `customizable`, `text_fields`, `uploadable_files`, `active`, `redirect_type`, `id_product_redirected`, `available_for_order`, `available_date`, `condition`, `show_price`, `indexed`, `visibility`, `cache_default_attribute`, `advanced_stock_management`, `date_add`, `date_upd`, `pack_stock_type`) VALUES ('1', '3', '0', 'A.IBR309515104QDMZ3RBT', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '45', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '188.903', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '', '0', '1', '0000-00-00', 'new', '1', '0', 'both', '0', '0', '2017-01-18 11:47:05', '2017-01-18 11:47:05', '3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be because of old remaining data in your `psmo_product` table, or even a bad configured sequence product ID generator.

You should cleanup your catalog (if you can) and upload it again. I recommend you `pscleaner` free module. If you will do this manually you must check `psmo_product_shop` too.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem as well, and I found the source of problem.

4294967295 seems to be max possible value of ID accepted by the system.

If you try to import the item with ID > 4294967295, prestashop sets the ID value as 4294967295, and further import with id "4294967295+1" is not possible, it tries to use the same id (4294967295).

So, you need to lower the numbers in your ID field in your csv file.